# Connect to ESXi 5.0 host from vSphere Client 5.1

Tags: esxi

We have multiple VMware clusters. Some are running 4.1 some 5.0 and some 5.1. We will be upgrading them all eventually, but with the client for 5.1 installed, before it will let me connect to a 4.1 or 5.0 cluster, it wants me to downgrade the vSphere Client.

I could understand the other way around, but this is very annoying.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't downgrade, it installs the various clients in parallel.  If you want to connect, then install the client.

Answer (score 0):

You have vcenter installed ?

Use a web client (web browser) not the standalone client.

If you do need the client 
keep a few admin vm's with installs of the clients and other needed tools on a standalone box